# Mobile First Platform - Cannot Register Device

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using MFP v8 Cordova v6.3.1 and Ionic v1.3, for a cordova mobile app, push is working fine on android, but I can't get it to work on iOS. Here are steps I have taken.

I have push turned ON in capabilities in xCode
I have push.mobileclient set under Security under the MFP Operations Console
App ID has push enabled and set up in the KeyChain

When I run the app first I get 
-Successfully intialized Push
-Push Supported: true
Then I register for subscriptions like this

```
var tags = ['all'];
        WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
        MFPPush.subscribe(
                         tags,
                         function(tags) {
                        console.log("Subscribed successfully");
                         },function(failureResponse){
                         console.log("Failed to subscribe:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
                         }
                         )
        );
```

Which give `Subscribed successfully`

And then I have

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken("push.mobileclient").then(
       MFPPush.registerDevice(
                              {},
                              function(successResponse) {
                             console.log("Successfully registered");
                              },
                              function(failureResponse) {
                              console.log("Failed to register device:" + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
                              }
                              )
       );
```

I don't see either the success callback or the failure callback which seems very weird to me?

However I do this the deviceID for the iPhone in the MFP Operations Console, and when I try to send a push to that device I get "The notification message was accepted for delivery"

But nothing ever comes to the phone?

What can I not receive pushes?

Thanks

**EDIT

[image]**

Cordov plugin list

```
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-context-menu 0.1.1 "Context Menu"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.4 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016101414 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2016070407 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.5.2 "Toast"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Why are you first subscribing the device for tags and only then register the device for push? It should be the other way around. Also, did you test push in the sample Cordova application?

Comment: What is your iOS version?

Comment: @IdanAdar iOS v10.0.1 and I have tried it with no subscriptions and it still has the same result and the same thing is happening when I run the sample Cordova push app. On the sample I hit "Is Push Supported" it says `true` then I press "Register Device" and nothing happens in the app or in the console?

Comment: Make sure that in Xcode you have the push entitlement enabled in the Capabilities screen.

Comment: @IdanAdar its turned on, for both apps see edit

Comment: do "cordova plugin list" and provide the list of plugins you have installed.

Comment: @IdanAdar see edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127392/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-idan-adar).

Comment: How did you solve the discussion in chat? I am facing the same problem

Comment: I solved it by deleting the Xcode project and re-cloning it from repo.
Also, the callback is not called in the Simulator

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

1. On December 6th 2016 updated `cordova-plugin-mfp` and `cordova-plugin-mfp-push` were released. You may want to try and update your plug-ins and test again
2. iOS 10 requires the Keychain Sharing capability enabled in the Capabilities tab in Xcode. Make sure this capability is enabled.